# Migration from 1.9.3.x to Magento 2.3.5 issue multi-website data not migrate

Tags: multistore, multi-website, data-migration-tool, magento2.3.5-p1, magento-1.9.3.8

I have migrated from **Magento1.9.3.x to Magento2.3.5**  after check **multi-website** data not convert. anyone, please guide how to check the issue.

Thank You